# Modifying how Hibernate's QueryImpl.class works

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a cache that contains a subset of data found in my database. I would like Hibernate to check that cache first instead of querying the database directly.

For example, in getResultList(), I would like to check the cache first. When there is a hit, construct the list of objects and return to DAO. Otherwise, query the database as Hibernate would.

My question is how do I configure Hibernate such that it uses my implementation of the function getResultList().

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "RedundantCast" })
public List<X> getResultList() {
    try {


        // CHECK EXTERNAL CACHE HERE *************************
        // start pseudo code...
        if (found in cache)
           get data from cache
           put data into a collection
           return collection
        else
           return (List<X>) query.list();
        // end pseudo code...


    }
    catch (QueryExecutionRequestException he) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(he);
    }
    catch( TypeMismatchException e ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
    catch (HibernateException he) {
        throw getEntityManager().convert( he );
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to reinvent the second-level cache. Why don't you use a second-level cache?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have considered using that but I would like to use the external cache because a) it already exists and b) it provides additional functionality that the 2nd-level cache does not. For example, an independent application can update the cache and my application will be aware of the change.

Comment: Am I on the right track here? I thought about adding this check to my DAO. But the problem is I have 100+ of these which means a lot of similar changes. And furthermore, this is unconventional therefore difficult for future developers to adopt.

Comment: I am with _JB Nizet_ on this. What if you wanted to load a list and some of the required entities were in cache and some not?

Comment: One big problem you will face is, the legacy cached items are probably not managed entities of Hibernate (they are detached objects or even transient ones).  Simply returning it from the query is not going to work well with other entities.